# How do I populate my ArrayList with String arrays? All while associating them with the correlating int and string I split...

Tags: java, arraylist, split

1. First I split

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ```
       String a = "l/o/c/a/ll/y";
       String b = "18/22/17/9/18/8";
       String [] c = a.split("/");
       String [] d = b.split("/");
       for(int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(d[i]+" = " + c[i]);
       }
   ```

18=l, 22=o, 17=c, 9=a, 18=ll, 8=y

2. Next I want to build a list of lists where the int is the list ID and the chars populates the ID they associate with.

ie ArrayList< {18[l,ll]}, {22[o]}, {17[c]}, {9[a]}, {8[y]}  >

Comment: Use. A. [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)!

Comment: Don't you want a Map<Integer, List<String>> instead?